# is it possible to develop live Streaming tv in Android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to develop Google TV apps using a Mac and an actual Google TV device? (2

Answer (score 0):

Yes you just need [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=macosx), [Eclipse's ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html), and the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). All the current Google TV (Logitec Revues, and Sony's Line) devices have wireless Debugging via AVD so its really simple to develop on.

Comment: @ralpgabb yes try exoplayer sample, it has everything needed.